# Fix location of Plotly hover legend in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-plotly

Suppose you have a plotly graph:

```
library(plotly)
library(forecast)

p <- ggplot(fortify(forecast::gold), aes(x, y)) + geom_line()
fig <- ggplotly(p)
fig <- fig %>% style(line = list(color = 'gold'), hoverinfo = "y", traces = 1)
```

Is it possible to fix the location of plotly's legend (hoverinfo) to the right hand side of the graph, perhaps beyond the extent of the plotted data? I short, I would like to see the hover data, but I don't want the hover info box to follow the mouse.

This screenshot is a good example of where the legend info could reside. The red, green and blue legend text stays in a fixed location while the numbers change as you mouse over different parts of the graph (this non-Shiny dashboard can be viewed [here](https://tracktherecovery.org)).

[image]